# Matching 2 different dataframes to return value and then compare

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to match these 2 dataframes of different size, get the matched field, and then compare if it is bigger or smaller.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'id': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
        'id2': ['', '', '', 'b1', 'b2'],
        'cost':[1,2,3,4,5]}, columns = ['first_name', 'id','id2','cost'])
df

    first_name  id  id2 cost
0   Jason   a1      1
1   Molly   a2      2
2   Tina    a3      3
3   Jake    a4  b1  4
4   Amy     a5  b2  5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','b1','b2','b3'],'cost':[1,2,3,4,6,6]},columns = ['id','cost'])
df2


id  cost
0   a1  1
1   a2  2
2   a3  3
3   b1  4
4   b2  3
5   b3  6
```

The expected results is:

```
first_name  id  id2 cost
0   Jason   a1      1
1   Molly   a2      2
2   Tina    a3      3
3   Jake    a4  b1  4
```

The match is being done on df on id1 and id2, compared to df2 on id. Though b2 is in id, it is not included because the cost matched in df2 is bigger than the cost in df.

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
df[(df['id'].isin(df2['id']) == True) | (df['id2'].isin(df2['id']) == True)]

    first_name  id  id2 cost
0   Jason   a1      1
1   Molly   a2      2
2   Tina    a3      3
3   Jake    a4  b1  4
4   Amy a5  b2  5
```

I seem to be having trouble to also compare the cost and exclude those that are smaller than the matched cost.

This is an example, the piece I am working on has 1.8 million records in df and to be matched to 170 thousand records in df2. Here I am comparing 2 columns, but there are 4 columns I need to match in df.

I hope this makes sense, because efficiency is at consideration now as well, merging the dataframe over 4 times does not make sense.

Another example:

```
df

    first_name  id  id2 cost
0   Jason   a1      7
1   Molly   a2      2
2   Tina    a3      3
3   Jake    a4  b1  4
4   Amy     a5  b2  8

df2


id  cost
0   a1  6
1   a2  2
2   a3  3
3   b1  4
4   b2  6
5   b3  6
```

In the example above,

The expected results would be:

```
first_name  id  id2 cost
1   Molly   a2      2
2   Tina    a3      3
3   Jake    a4  b1  4
```

So a1,a2,a3,a4,b1 and b2 matches, but because cost in a1 and b2 is bigger than cost in df2.cost. They are excluded.

Corrected my above example as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could `df2` also have `a4` in column `id`? And if so, which cost would you pick, `a4` or `b1`?

Comment: Yes `df2` could also have `a4` in the column `id`. The expected result is whatever record from df where, `df.id` or `df.id2` that appears in `df2.id` and if `cost` in df is smaller than `cost` in df2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) values in columns `id` and `id2` by `df2` with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replacing not numbers to `NaN`. Last compare by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (~((df[['id','id2']].replace(df2.set_index('id')['cost'])
                        .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
                        .gt(df.cost, axis=0)).any(1) )


print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
  first_name  id id2  cost
0      Jason  a1        10
1      Molly  a2         2
2       Tina  a3         3
3       Jake  a4  b1     4
```

Comment: Will this also apply in cases where cost has to be specifically smaller than cost in df2 where df.id and df.id2 matches df2.id?

Comment: Do you think smaller length? If yes, I think it can works nice.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of `.isin` is not well. If we take a look at `df.id2`, even though it is in `df2.id`, the results should not return a record for it because the cost is bigger. Something like where `df.cost <= df2.cost` Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Made a correction, sorry I have been working on this for hours.

Comment: We might have updated the same time. Sorry. If we build with; `df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'id': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
        'id2': ['', '', '', 'b1', 'b2'],
        'cost':[10,2,3,4,5]}, columns = ['first_name', 'id','id2','cost'])` for df and `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3','b1','b2','b3'],'cost':[10,2,3,4,6,6]},columns = ['id','cost'])` it seems the results are not expected. Again, after matching specific for the id. Cost have to be smaller based on the matched cost.

Comment: And what is expected?

Comment: Records a1, a2, a3, b1 from df. b2 does not return because though matches with df2.id, the cost in df is smaller than df2 after matched.

Comment: For me it return print (pd.DataFrame({'id2': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: 'b1', 4: 'b2'}, 'first_name': {0: 'Jason', 1: 'Molly', 2: 'Tina', 3: 'Jake', 4: 'Amy'}, 'cost': {0: 10, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'id': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a2', 2: 'a3', 3: 'a4', 4: 'a5'}})), what is desired output?

Comment: Hey thanks for helping so much yea? This:    print (pd.DataFrame({'id2': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: 'b1'}, 'first_name': {0: 'Jason', 1: 'Molly', 2: 'Tina', 3: 'Jake'}, 'cost': {0: 10, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'id': {0: 'a1', 1: 'a2', 2: 'a3', 3: 'a4',}}))